# Delete duplicate rows with same values in table but retain one row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

This is one of the query in my stored procedure, where I am inserting the records from `Main` table to duplicate table and after this I would like to delete the duplicate rows in my main table more than one.

This is my code

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM [JOB] 
            WHERE 
              AND ExternalSourceId = @ExternalSourceId 
              AND Id <> @Id 
              AND IsActive = 1)
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DupJob 
        SELECT * 
        FROM [JOB] j 
        WHERE 
          AND ExternalSourceId = @ExternalSourceId 
          AND Id <> @Id 
          AND IsActive = 1 
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DupJob dj WHERE J.Id = dj.Id)     
    -- the delete should delete all duplicates except one ?
 END
```

Seeking help to proceed, thanks

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: i just want a way to proceed at the delete statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number()` and a CTE is a convenient way to do this.  I'm not sure exactly what the logic you want is, but it is something like this:

```
with todelete as (
      select j.*,
             row_number() over (partition by OrganizationName, JobTitle, PostalCode, ExternalSourceId)
                                order by id) as seqnum
      from job j
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

This will keep one row per the columns in the `partition by`, the one with the minimum value of `id`.

Comment: I thought the same either to use row_number() or rank(). Can i use the same above combined with my query ? pls suggest

Comment: rank and row number are subtly different in how they treat ties.  Without ties, they are equivalent.